# Subtraction of a sub-squence and a sequence explanation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, self-learning

In my assignment I have the following question,

> True of false:
>
> Let $a_{n}$ be a sequence. If $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (a_{2n}-a_{n})=0$$ Then $a_{n}$ is convergent.

The statment is false and the following example, which I don't understand, prove it:

$a_n = \begin{cases} 1 & n=2^k, k\in \Bbb N \\ 
0 & n\ne2^k \end{cases}$

However, I don't understand why.

**My main question is: What does the subtraction $(a_{2^k}-a_n)$ do?**

In my understanding, the sequence $a_{2^k}$ takes all the indexes that are equal to 2 in power of k, meaning 2,4,8,... and gives them the value $1$. However in the sequence $a_n$ we have a lot of values, such as 0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,...

So if I make a subtraction I get the following:

$$(a_{2^k}-a_n)=(1-0,1-1,1-0,1-1,...)$$
Since in my understanding the subsequence always gets the value $1$.

Where did I get it wrong? Clearly, I am getting it VERY wrong.

You help is appriciated.

Alan

Comment: It looks like you're getting a bit mixed up with the indices and the actual value of $a_n$. You write $a_{2^k} - a_{n}$ whereas it is really $a_{2n} - a_n$. Whenever $n = 2^k$ this term is $a_{2^{k + 1}} - a_{2^k} = 1 - 1 = 0$. Otherwise it's $0 - 0 = 0$. So it's always $0$.

Comment: If you look back at the original True/False question statement, you'll notice that it's *multiplication*, not exponentiation used.

Comment: So your main mistake is the term you have written in bold. Notice that $k$ is just being used as "dummy variable"- to test whether $n$ is a perfect power of $2$. It could be stated without $k$ at all, e.g. by saying $log_2(k)$ is an integer.

Comment: @ColmBhandal Thank you, I did mix things up.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that $2n$ is only a power of $2$ exactly when $n$ is a power of $2$. So the subtraction always gives you $0$. But on its own, the series flips from $0$ to $1$ and so never converges.